# onLoad not working in mozilla firefox while moving from one to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using a pagination for navigation and onLoad method for some of the requirements to work around it is working well in other browsers where as in mozilla it gets called at a time for all the pages. is there a  method to work with this

exp.js

```
  function details(svgid,gid1,gid2,gid3,gid4,gid5,gid6)
    {
        var a = document.getElementById(svgid);
        var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
        console.log(svgDoc)
        if(svgid==svg_seen1)
        {
            if(document.getElementById(screen_one_filed_one).value=='')
            {
                svgDoc.getElementById(gid1).childNodes[0].textContent=svgDoc.getElementById(gid1).childNodes[0].textContent;
                svgDoc.getElementById(gid2).childNodes[0].textContent= svgDoc.getElementById(gid2).childNodes[0].textContent;
            }
            else
            { 
                svgDoc.getElementById(gid1).childNodes[0].textContent=document.getElementById(screen_one_filed_one).value;
                svgDoc.getElementById(gid2).childNodes[0].textContent= document.getElementById(screen_one_filed_two).value;
            }  
        }
}
```

input.html

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/images/svg files/Scene_01.svg" id='svgObject' onload="details(this.id,svg_seen1_id1,svg_seen1_id2);">
```

there are multiple objects in pagination and onLoad is being called at a time

Comment: Show your efforts. Without efforts it may not possible to give you an answer.

Comment: just edited have a look

Comment: object have no onload event but body have onload event. you should put your code in body.

Comment: Give me your proper idea what do you want to execute and do in your code

Answer (score 0):

It is impossibile for someone to give you an answer if you don't even post your code here. The problem could be anywhere in your code.

EDIT: like someone other told you about the onload, you could use the onload event on the body in your HTML code or directly in tour JavaScript calling the body onload event